# Does helidon supports HTTP2?

Tags: helidon, helidon-httpclient, helidon-webclient

i want to start using Helidon for our project whcih is currently based on Spring Boot. Want to know if Helidon MP or Helidon SE supports HTTP2 server and clients?

Answer (score 5):

[Yes, it has for some time now](https://medium.com/helidon/http-2-support-in-helidon-25c81ec8f86b).